# Firestore write Timestamp Field

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I want to write a timestamp field into a Firestore document in a typescript project.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

const myDoc = {
     myDate: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
    }

    const myDocument = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('col')
        .doc('myId')
        .set(myDoc)
```

Unfortunately, the generated document contains for `MyDate`  a string field and not a date/time field as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 15-June-2021:

For write a new document with set use this:

```
const MyDoc = {
  MyDate: new Date(),
}
```

For update an existing document with update use this:

```
const MyDoc = {
  MyDate: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
}

const myDocument = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('col')
    .doc('myId')
    .update(myDoc)
```

I cannot explain why there is a difference.